# How to perform prediction using predict_generator on unlabeled test data in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification

I'm trying to build an image classification model. It's a 4 class image classification. Here is my code for building image generators and running the training:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.,
                               rotation_range=30,
                               horizontal_flip=True,
                               validation_split=0.1)


train_generator = image_gen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, target_size=(299, 299), 
                                                class_mode='categorical', batch_size=20,
                                                subset='training')

validation_generator = image_gen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, target_size=(299, 299), 
                                                class_mode='categorical', batch_size=20,
                                                subset='validation')

model.compile(Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                                         metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=int(440/20), epochs=20, 
                              validation_data=validation_generator, 
                              validation_steps=int(42/20))
```

I was able to get train and validation work perfectly because the images in *train* directory are stored in a separate folder for each class. But, as you can see below, the *test* directory has 100 images and no folders inside it. It also doesn't have any labels and only contains image files.

How can I do prediction on the image files in *test* folder using Keras?

[image: dataset directory structure]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are interested to only perform prediction, you can load the images by a simple hack like this:

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)

test_generator = test_datagen('PATH_TO_DATASET_DIR/Dataset',
                              # only read images from `test` directory
                              classes=['test'],
                              # don't generate labels
                              class_mode=None,
                              # don't shuffle
                              shuffle=False,
                              # use same size as in training
                              target_size=(299, 299))

preds = model.predict_generator(test_generator)
```

You can access `test_generator.filenames` to get a list of corresponding filenames so that you can map them to their corresponding prediction.

---

**Update (as requested in comments section):** if you want to map predicted classes to filenames, first you must find the predicted classes. If your model is a classification model, then probably it has a softmax layer as the classifier. So the values in `preds` would be probabilities. Use `np.argmax` method to find the index with highest probability:

```
preds_cls_idx = preds.argmax(axis=-1)
```

So this gives you the indices of predicted classes. Now we need to map indices to their string labels (i.e. "car", "bike", etc.) which are provided by training generator in `class_indices` attribute:

```
import numpy as np

idx_to_cls = {v: k for k, v in train_generator.class_indices.items()}
preds_cls = np.vectorize(idx_to_cls.get)(preds_cls_idx)
filenames_to_cls = list(zip(test_generator.filenames, preds_cls))
```

Comment: Should I use `"PATH_TO_DATASET_DIR/Dataset/test"` (or) `""PATH_TO_DATASET_DIR/Dataset"`? I asked this because the test files are in test folder.

Comment: @user_12 No, you should use `PATH_TO_DATASET_DIR/Dataset` and then limit it using `classes=['test']`. That's actually the hack I was referring to.

Comment: okay. Thank a lot. I'll test it and get back. If possible can you also provide some sample code on how can I use the predictions names(i.e car or bike etc.) and map it to their filenames?

Comment: In test_generator do I have to give same target_size? i.e (299, 299)

Comment: @user_12 Oops! Yes, I missed that. I just edited my answer and added it.

Comment: Can you also tell me do I need to use batch_size in test_generator. or should I set it to 1? For train i used batch size of 20

Comment: @user_12 No, it's value is not important (except for efficiency, i.e. using all the resources available). The default batch size would be 32.

Comment: @today : your code depends on `train_generator.class_indices`. A problem can occur if you do not have the train data available, if it was trained by another team or person for example, and you only have the model and test data.

Answer (score 4):

your folder structure be like `testfolder/folderofallclassfiles`

you can use

```
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=pred_dir,
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=False
)
```

before prediction i would also use reset to avoid unwanted outputs

EDIT:

For your purpose you need to know which image is associated with which prediction. The problem is that the data-generator start at different positions in the dataset each time we use the generator, thus giving us different outputs everytime. So, in order to restart at the beginning of the dataset in each call to `predict_generator()` you would need to exactly match the number of iterations and batches to the dataset-size.
There are multiple ways to encounter this

a)  You can see the internal batch-counter using `batch_index` of generator
b) create a new data-generator before each call to `predict_generator()`
c) there is a better and simpler way, which is to call `reset()` on the generator, and if you have set `shuffle=False` in `flow_from_directory` then it should start over from the beginning of the dataset and give the exact same output each time, so now the ordering of `testgen.filenames` and `testgen.classes` matches

```
test_generator.reset()
```

Prediction

```
prediction = model.predict_generator(test_generator,verbose=1,steps=numberofimages/batch_size)
```

**To map the filename with prediction**

`predict_generator` gives output in probabilities so at first we need to convert them to class number like 0,1..

```
predicted_class = np.argmax(prediction,axis=1)
```

next step would be to convert those class number into actual class names

```
l = dict((v,k) for k,v in training_set.class_indices.items())
prednames = [l[k] for k in predicted_classes]
```

getting filenames

```
filenames = test_generator.filenames
```

Finally creating df

```
finaldf = pd.DataFrame({'Filename': filenames,'Prediction': prednames})
```

Comment: Why do we have to use `test_generator.reset()`? I didn't get what you mean by unwanted outputs? We'll only get probabilities right,

Comment: @user_12 Please check the edit I have added the explanation

Comment: Could I ask a question about this? I asked the full question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71125533/imagedatagenerator-predict-class-why-are-the-predictions-not-correctly-convert . But I have a directory called all_classes which is a set of images from two classes, and I want to use this as my test set for my model. When I follow @today's answer above, it returns just a numpy array of 0s. Can someone explain my issue (probably easiest to link to full question), I can't see anything here that I did differently?