# ImageDataGenerator Predict Class - Why are the predictions not correctly converting from probabilities to predicted class?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, tf.keras

I have a directory set up like this:

images

```
-- val
    --class1
    --class2
-- test
   --all_classes
-- train
    --class1
    --class2
```

In each dir is a set of images. I want to predict if each image in test belongs to class 1 or class 2.

I wrote this to read in the training and validation data:

```
train_path = "/content/drive/train/"
valid_path = "/content/drive/val/"

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
  directory=train_path,
  batch_size=32,
  class_mode='binary',
  target_size=(150,150)
)

validation_generator=test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
  directory=valid_path,
  batch_size=32,
  class_mode='binary',
  target_size=(150,150)
)
```

Created a network:

```
def create_network(): 
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Input(shape=(150,150,3)))

  model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3,strides=(1, 1),activation='relu', padding='valid', dilation_rate=1))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

  model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',padding='valid', dilation_rate=1))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))

  model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
  plot_model(model, to_file='/content/drive/question1_model.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)

  model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',
                   loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
                   metrics = ['accuracy'])
  return model
```

Fit the model:

```
def fit_model(train_generator=train_generator, validation_generator=validation_generator,network=create_network()):
  checkpoint_path = "/content/drive/question1_checkpoint.h5"
  checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

  callbacks_list = [
      callbacks.EarlyStopping(
          monitor = 'accuracy',
          patience = 5,
      ),

      callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
          filepath=checkpoint_path,
          monitor = 'val_loss',
          #save_weights_only=True,
          save_best_only=True,
      ),

  ]

  model = network
  history = model.fit(train_generator,
                      epochs=200,
                      validation_data=validation_generator,
                      batch_size=32, 
                      callbacks = callbacks_list,
                      verbose=1
                      )
  return history,model,time_taken

history,model = fit_model(train_generator,validation_generator)
```

The accuracy and val accuracy of the model is >80%, and I loaded it back in to predict:

```
model = load_model('/content/drive/question1_checkpoint.h5')
```

And then I wanted to predict a set of images in test directory:

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_path = "/content/drive/test/"

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
  directory=test_path,
  batch_size=16,
  class_mode='binary',
  target_size=(150,150),
  shuffle = False
)
test_generator.reset()
filenames = test_generator.filenames
nb_samples = len(filenames)
batch_size=16
predict = model.predict(test_generator,steps=test_generator.n/batch_size)
```

When I print the start of predict, I can see:

```
[[6.09035552e-01]
 [2.47541070e-02]
 [7.37663209e-02]
 [5.22839129e-02]
 [2.94408262e-01]
 [1.39171720e-01]
 [6.15863085e-01]
```

Which I think gives me the probability for class 1 right. But then when I print the class of each prediction with:

```
predicted_class_indices=np.argmax(predict,axis=-1)
print(predicted_class_indices)
```

The output is:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

This means that my predicted probabilities are not being correctly translated to the class right? because for example 2.47541070e-02 is 0.02, whereas 6.09035552e-01 is 0.60, so shouldn't these have been predicted to be in different classes? Could someone show me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This code is giving me below output: (I have taken 10 images for test - 5 dog's images, 5 cat's images after training the model with same binary class dataset).

```
nb_samples = len(filenames)
batch_size=5
predict = model.predict(test_generator,steps=test_generator.n/batch_size)
predict
```

Output:

```
array([[0.06690815],
       [0.7787118 ],
       [0.109512  ],
       [0.39706784],
       [0.07243159],
       [0.61042166],
       [0.5808931 ],
       [0.86361384],
       [0.9961897 ],
       [0.61571515]], dtype=float32)
```

Whcih is right as you have used [sigmoid](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/sigmoid) activation function in final layer then output range will be from 0 to 1.

Please do not use `argmax` for `sigmoid` values. You can use `argmax` method while using [softmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/softmax) activation function to find the highest probablities values of class among other class probabilities.

Here you can use below code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

predictions = tf.where(predict <= 0.5, 0, 1)

print('Predictions:\n', predictions.numpy())
```

Output:

```
Predictions:

 [[0]
 [1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]]
```